# What do the standards (C++) say about compile time initialization?

Tags: c++, initialization, standards

In other words, when is a "static const" equivalent to a "#define"?
I searched a lot and can't find anything.
This is very relevant for global initialization dependencies (I know, globals are evil, but life is evil too!).

I am sure the standard does not force, but it probably mentions it.

E.g.:

```
static const int a = 2;  // Always seen it as compile time
static const int b = 2 * a;  // Compile time
static const float c = 3.14;  // Compile time
static const float d = c * 1.1 ;  // I know the evils of compile time here, but I've seen it both ways (compile and run time)
static const char e = 'p' ;  // Compile time
static const int *f = NULL;  // Never really tried it :)
```

Comment: If you are using C++11 I believe that for these cases if you replace `const` with `constexpr` you can be absolutely sure that these will be evaluated at compile time. Also, prefer `nullptr` to `NULL`. Sadly, I do not have a copy of the standard to quote from, so I don't have a legitimate answer for your question.

Comment: It doesn't mention that it has to, but it does explicitly mention that it can. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21735890/where-and-how-are-constants-stored/21736779#21736779

Comment: I am very much interested in C++03 standard too, because unfortunately it is old code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is specified by C++11 3.6.2: *constant initialization* is performed...

> if an object with static or thread storage duration is not initialized by a constructor call and if every full-expression that appears in its initializer is a constant expression.

This is your situation, except for `d`: `int` and `float` don't have constructors, and the initializer is a literal, which is a constant expression. Constant initialization is part of *static initialization*, and:

> Static initialization shall be performed before any dynamic initialization takes place.

The standard doesn't explicitly prescribe an implementation, but there is no ordering of static initializations, and it is understood that the initial values are essentially provided at load time, and no code executes in order to get those global variables to have their initial values.

The variable `d` does not meet these criteria since its initializer is not a constant expression (because `c` is not a constant expression). The standard allows `d` to be initialized either dynamically or statically.

Comment: There is *some* ordering of static initializations.  It's undefined across translation units, and for template static members it gets hairy, but in the question, for instance, the order is well defined (order of declaration within a single translation unit).  All this is detailed shorty after your second quote, in 3.6.2.

Comment: @SamCristall: Those are about *dynamic* initialization. There's no ordering among *static* initializations (which are zero- and constant initialization). The word "static" is a bit overused, though.

Comment: Ahh, I see!  Thank you for the clarification.  The terminology is definitely overused -- `static` could use a few dozen less meanings.

Comment: I am not sure that "static initialization" applies to (c * 1.1), and that is one that very much interests me.  In general, could any "static initialization" be done at compile time?

Comment: @Frigg: Absolutely right, I missed that one. It's definitely *not* guaranteed to be in the static phase, because `c` is not a constant expression (it would have to be declared `constexpr` for that). The initialization *may* be hoisted into the static phase, but doesn't have to.

Comment: @Frigg: You can get some interesting unspecified behaviour when initializers depend on other variables that may or may not be hoisted into the static phase; there's an example in the standard in 3.6.2/3.

Comment: Indeed, I know it all too well.  I was hoping to save myself a large amount of work if I could be certain (in view of the standard) that some global variables would be compile time initialized! I have always known the clear cases, and stayed far away from the grey zones, but now I have to plunge in the grey zones against my will.

Comment: @Frigg: Just declare `c` as `constexpr`. Then everything is definite.

Comment: Unfortunately `constexpr` is not an option at this point (VS2012, among others, does not support it).  But on this subject, will the compiler give an error if trying to set a `constexpr` variable that cannot be compile time initialized?

Answer (score 1):

Answering: 'In other words, when is a "static const" equivalent to a "#define"?'

Never, the first is part of the programming language, the latter is a preprocessor text processing directive.

Comment: Well that was not a question by itself, it referred to compile time initialization equivalence.  And in that context, they are equivalent sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring static const vs a define are two different things. A value replaced by define can non-const and non-static.

```
#MY_VAR 9
static const int a = MY_VAR;
int b = MY_VAR;
```

Defines essentially precompile time string replacement. Static and const keywords work all together different.