# Defining variables vs calculating on the fly

Tags: c++, variables, math

In terms of readability and memory usage/ processing speed is it better to define a variable, modify it and output the variable or to just output a result? eg:

```
int a = 1, b = 2, c;
c = a+b;
std::cout << c << std::endl;
```

vs

```
int a = 1, b = 2;
std::cout << a+b << std::endl;
```

Thanks

Comment: If you are using an optimizing compiler, the answer is "it doesn't make a difference" (especially in such trivial examples).

Comment: In any decent compiler either versions are equivalent.

Comment: In terms of readability, it's completely objective. In terms of processing speed you can either benchmark the two different variants, or look at the generated assembly code.

Comment: Thanks, figured it wouldn't be a massive difference.

Comment: For objects of type such as int, it shouldn't make much, if any, difference in performance. Same for small POD types. If you name the variables sensibly, it will make a huge difference in readability and maintainability.

Comment: @niallmcfc "not a massive difference" is true if the compiler doesn't do anything fancy. But if you use constexpr stuff, then you can dramatically reduce the process speed, memory usage, and instruction size of your code with less-trivial examples. But premature optimization is the root of all evil. But we have to optimize.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21735890/where-and-how-are-constants-stored/21736779#21736779

Comment: @JoachimPileborg i'd take measurement over eye-balling assembly any day

Comment: @TemplateRex I agree, especially since fewer instructions doesn't necessarily mean that the code will be quicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well with this example processing speed and space is negligible. So small and so few instructions.

But in the grand scheme of things the answer is -- well it depends.

The term "better" is in the eye of the beholder. What is better for one program might not be better for another (this includes readability). What may work in one instance may not work in another. Or in the end it could be negligible (arithmetic instructions are pretty fast depending on the scope of what you need and int, double, char, float data types are relatively small and well defined so you know how much memory you are taking up).

Here you do not define if these variables were declared on the stack or the heap. If on the stack then it doesn't matter if you declared it because after the function that these variables live in ends, the memory gets released. If on the heap you may not want to declare millions of variables just to sit there. But then again you may need them there.

So its based almost entirely on a case by case bases when dealing with bigger projects.
And you tell me what is better here?

```
 int result = (3434*234+3423-4/3*23< 233+5435*234+342)? (int)(234+234+234234/34):(int)(2+3*234);
 std::cout << result << std::endl;
```

OR

```
 double x =  3434*234+3423-4/3*23;
 double y = 233+5435*234+342;
 double a = 234+234+234234/34;
 double b = 2+3*234;
 int result = 0;
 if( x>y) result = a;
 else result = b;
 std::cout << result << std::endl;
```

in the end it these do the same things are the same with negligble difference but which one is easier to read?

Comment: One word for you: constant folding.

Answer (score 1):

Your question on memory is easy to answer, variables are stored identifiers so each take a couple bytes (bytes store 8 bits or binary digits) to store.  That being said, a byte is almost no memory, meaning that ultimately it has no net effect.  In terms of RAM (or Random Access Memory) a byte is again, almost negligible meaning that defining a, b, and c is barely slower than just calculating a + b.  Makes sense?