# where are constexpr variables stored

Tags: c++, memory-management, constexpr

I saw that `constexpr` variables are highly discussed on stack overflow. But there is one thing no one talks about:

### Where are constexpr variables stored?

Everyone knows the memory location tables of C and C++ programs.

- stack
- heap
- static
- text

**Operating Systems (like Linux)** 
For operating systems, executable code and all the static variables get copied from the hard drive disc into the allocated areas of text, static ect. in the RAM. From there the program starts as a process.

**Embedded Systems (like Atmel Controller)** 
For an embedded system, this is different. Here the executable code and the literals are permanently stored in a flash Memory; only the static Variables get copied into the RAM.

**text or static area** 
I understand the benefits of `constexpr` compared to `#defines`, but for an embedded system programmer, there is always the performance question. On embedded systems, RAM is an expensive resource. So, I need to know if `constexpr` variables get stored in the text or in the static area. Or more precisely, are they permanently stored in the flash memory or do they get really created as variable into the RAM of an embedded system?

Comment: Why would they necessarily be "stored" at all? If the expression evaluates to a simple integer constant, it could just end up as an immediate value in the generated assembly, for example, or perhaps loaded from the function's own constant pool (i.e., still within the code segment).

Comment: Compilers are usually smart enough to avoid using read/write memory for read-only objects.  So it's unlikely that your `constexpr` will end up occupying RAM.  Whether it's stored as a literal in flash, or encoded as an immediate operand in the code itself, or computed at runtime, or even optimized entirely out of existence, may depend on a lot of factors.

Comment: In some cases `constexpr` won't exist after compilation at all. They drive the generation of code but they don't have to exist in the code (or the data).

Comment: *"Everyone knows the memory location tables of C and C++ programs."* -- I guess I am a no one, since I am not part of this "everyone"? Last I checked, C and C++ were agnostic on the subject of memory locations, in part so that embedded systems can handle those locations differently than a PC.

Comment: Hmm.. I searched SO for `[c++] Where are constexpr variables stored` and found [Where and how are constants stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21735890/). I guess that is not a duplicate because this question claims that the question is something "no one talks about", and I wouldn't want to claim that those contributors are no ones. I guess one could conjecture that changing from `const` to `constexpr` might cause a value to move from flash memory to RAM? Still. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21736779) seems to address the current question well enough.

Comment: They are stored in the same place they would be if they weren't constexpr. Constexpr does not affect storage class. (Of course, compilers are encouraged to optimize out constexpr variables entirely.)

Comment: Sometimes it's even embedded in the code instruction (e.g. cmp ecx,,3)

Answer (score 3):

`constexpr` does not change the storage class of a variable. So the presence of `constexpr` does not change where the compiler can put the variable.

There are however some important characteristics of `constexpr` variables. Any variable could have these characteristics, but the `constexpr` qualifier specifically requires:

1. The variable cannot be changed (is implicitly `const`).
2. The variable is initialized with a compile-time constant expression.

Given these facts, the compiler can put the storage basically anywhere. If the type matches a register type and the value is of sufficient size that it can be loaded via a single "load literal" opcode, the compiler could convert every use of the variable into simply loading the literal value into a register.

Of course, if you start doing things like getting the address of the variable, it may have to take up actual storage. But even that depends on how good the compiler is at inlining.